# Trouble setting up Jenkins for GIT

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

I have been trying to set up Jenkins on my MAC for CI.
 I have generated a public key as a Jenkins user and placed it on my git server in the associated_keys file. It still throws up an error saying permission denied.
 Could you please help me !!!!

Comment: You need to provide MUCH more information. How is git configured in Jenkins? When exactly do you get this error? Can you post some of your console output from Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Jenkins to use git for the first time typically fails because SSH will give a warning and ask for confirmation the first time it tries to connect to a host. Something like this:

```
The authenticity of host 'example.com (10.66.77.88)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ae:51:f4:c7:c5:3a:54:f2:96:2c:59:ff:e3:59:52:a2.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

In an interactive session you can type `y` and the host will be added to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` so that you don't get the warning subsequently, but when Jenkins sees this it will fail.

To fix this, `sudo su jenkins` on your machine and try doing a git clone manually as the `jenkins` user. You can then confirm the host's validity and from then on Jenkins will be able to connect no problem.

This is a very common pitfall, so I assume it may be what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could try is to fix the key file name. From "man ssh"

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
         Lists the public keys (DSA/ECDSA/RSA) that can be used for log-
         ging in as this user.
```